# Vlookup a Cell which Contains a Part of Other Cell but not that Straightforward

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

Hi guys and all Excel gurus, I am stuck with this one excel problem which I cannot solve. I tried using Index, Match, Vlookup but to no avail.

Basically I tried getting Column D displays Value from Column B if the Value of Column C contains part of the value in Column A.

So what I'm dealing with is something kind of like this:
Fixed the table display

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Header     Column A   Column B   Column C  Column D  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Row 1      111        AAA        1111                |
| Row 2      222        BBB        112                 |
| Row 3      333        CCC        2225                |
| Row 4      444        DDD        333                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

So my expected result would be:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Header     Column A   Column B   Column C  Column D  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| Row 1      111        AAA        1111      AAA       |
| Row 2      222        BBB        112       N/A       |
| Row 3      333        CCC        2225      BBB       |
| Row 4      444        DDD        333       CCC       |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sorry for the poor table display and explanation. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5, MATCH(1,IF(ISERR(FIND($B$2:$B$5, $D2)),0,1),0))
```

, where `5` is the last data row. Enter as an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in `E2`, then drag down.

BTW on row 4 it gives `CCC`, not `N/A`.

Comment: Hi GSerg, thank you for the formula, however it does not seem to work for me. I Put the formula on E2 as an array formula, however excel gave me just #N/A as the answer. I wonder why would D2 is included in the formula.

@Soren Holten Hansen thank you for fixing my table bro.

Comment: @user3506172 I thought your data starts at `B2`, and `Row 1` is actual data in `A2`. If data actually starts at `A1` then shift everything in the formula up and left one cell, and put it in `D1`. `=INDEX($B$1:$B$4, MATCH(1,IF(ISERR(FIND($A$1:$A$4, $C1)),0,1),0))`

Comment: Awesome Solution GSreg, many thanks for your help. Have a good day GSerg.

Comment: Btw if you do not mind explaining the formula for me. Why do we put 1 after Match and what will the IF and ISERR and Find do? I initially thought that Index and Match solely can be used to solved the above problem.

Comment: `FIND($B$2:$B$5, $D2)` creates an array, one item for each cell in `$B$2:$B$5`, that contains either position of the respective text inside `D2`, or an error if the text is not found.

`IF(ISERR(that array, 0, 1))` transforms that array into an array of `0`s and `1`s, where `0` means not found, and `1` means found.

`MATCH(1, transformed array, 0)` finds position of first item in that array that has the value of `1` ("found").

Comment: GSerg you are an excel guru, you rock Man. Thanks for the super details explanation :)